# Error al iniciar una aplicación desplegada en weblogic 11g

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, jdeveloper, adfs

Buen día para todos!

Estoy implementado una aplicación web en weblogic 11g, al instalar el EAR no sucede ningún problema, error sucede cuando trato de iniciar la aplicación, el error que da es **java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key severe.no_factory_backup_failed**, ya he intentado varias soluciones a problemas similares pero no lo he podido solucionar, no sé si me podrían ayudar solucionando este problema.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por el mensaje parece ser que esta tratando de ubicar un archivo `.properties` y no lo encuentra en el path, en proyectos web los ubico en el `src/main/resources`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya solucioné, era un problema de versiones de JDeveloper, ya que estaba usando el 12c y como es un proyecto de hace unos años, necesitaba era usar la versión 11g.